# Query to replace default values with child's values with JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, sequelize.js

I want to JOIN on the same table, in order to get a list of Tags. My goal is that the Tags can be overwritten by the user with their own values :

- Tags without `accountId` are the default Tags for all users.
- The user can create his own Tags: no `defaultTagId` and a specified `accountId`.
- The user can edit a default Tag by creating a new line, with the ID of the Tag he wants to overwrite (`defaultTagId`).

Tags overwritten by a user should only appear once, the default row should no longer be returned, replaced by the previously created one.
In my example, "my todo" overwrite "DEFAULT TODO".

Here an example :

| id | accountId | name | color | defaultTagId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | DEFAULT TODO | #012345 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | DEFAULT DONE | #FFFFFF | NULL |
| 3 | NULL | my todo | #000000 | 1 |
| 4 | NULL | my new tag | #ABCDEF | NULL |

What I would like :

| name | color |
| --- | --- |
| my todo | #000000 |
| DEFAULT DONE | #FFFFFF |
| my new tag | #ABCDEF |

Here is a start of a query that does not work as I would like :

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(Tags.name, Tags2.name), Tags.id, Tags.name, Tags.accountId, Tags2.id, Tags2.name, Tags2.accountId
FROM Tags
LEFT JOIN Tags AS Tags2 ON Tags.defaultTagId = Tags2.id AND Tags.accountId IS NOT NULL
WHERE Tags.accountId IS NOT NULL OR (Tags.accountId IS NULL AND Tags2.id IS NULL);
```

PS : If you can make it work with Sequelize it's even better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with the following query:

```sql
SELECT Tags.*, T2.id, T2.name
FROM Tags
LEFT JOIN Tags AS T2 ON T2.defaultTagId = Tags.id OR Tags.defaultTagId = T2.id
WHERE T2.accountId IS NULL;
```